# Best way to return update status from repository layer in ASP.NET MVC WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Web API with Entity Framework and Backbone.js

I am working on an update module, where user is allowed to update his XYZ.

Now, there are 3 cases which may occur while updating

- Success
- Failed
- Not Found

So I have decided to use this enum called

```cs
enum UpdateStatus
{
    Success = 1,
    Failed = 0,
    NotFound = 2
}
```

so here is what my methods will look like

```cs
public UpdateStatus UpdateXYZ(Model model)
{
    var data = _repo.Table.where(m => m.id == model.id);
    if(data.count == 0)
    {
        return UpdateStatus.NotFound;
    }

    try
    {
        // update here
        return UpdateStatus.Sucess; 
    }
    catch
    {
        // log errors
        return UpdateStatus.Failed;
    }
}
```

Then later in the service layer I would be returning the same values to my web api action. And then in the web api action I would have something like...

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Details details)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //The server has fulfilled the request and the user agent SHOULD reset the document view which caused the request to be sent.
        //return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ResetContent);
        UpdateStatus = _magicService.UpdateXYZ(details);
        if (UpdateStatus.Success)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        else if(UpdateStatus.NotFound)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
    }
    else
    {
        string messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage + " - " + (x.Exception == null ? "" : x.Exception.Message)));
        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, messages.ToString());
    } 

}
```

I have defined my UpdateStatus enum in my repo layer and am using it in Service and Web layers also. Would like opinions on this approach or is there any other way I could have done this ?

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning `UpdateStatus.Failed` in the catch block? Is that a typo?

Comment: too much CTRL-C n CTRL-V I would say :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as long as your domain models are not leaving the boundaries of your Web API for which you should be using view models.

Comment: Your Web API actions should not take or return domain models as arguments.

Comment: why ? my web api action is not returning the domain models, but it is taking.

Comment: Because you are making your Web API dependent on your domain models. By using view models your API is more resilient to domain model changes without breaking existing clients. The view model's purpose is to have an exact representation of the entities that are traveling over the wire and what clients are seeing.

Comment: here I am using two models one in repo layer and other in service layer, I am not using any models in view(web) layer. What do u suggest on this approach ?

Comment: I suggest you using view models in your Web API tier. Your Web API action should take and pass only view models. So instead of `public HttpResponseMessage Put(Details details)` you should have `public HttpResponseMessage Put(DetailsViewModel details)`.